# Magento 2 - get customer address list with ajax in checkout page

Tags: magento2, api, checkout-page

Is there any way to call customer address list with ajax in checkout page? or maybe Magento already provide an API service to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/rest_endpoints.html

```
GET    /V1/customers/me/billingAddress
GET    /V1/customers/:customerId/billingAddress
GET    /V1/customers/me/shippingAddress
GET    /V1/customers/:customerId/shippingAddress
```